# overloading + operator in QString ,Qt

Tags: qt, overloading, overriding

I want to overload the + operator for my mainwindow class(or any other class) for Qstring. 
this is what I have done so far :

```
void operator+(QString a,QString b)
{
    qDebug()<<"works";
}
```

but the thing is, the QString + operator is already overloaded(to concatenate, I guess). 
so, if I use the above code, it results in ambiguity(both the signatures are same). 
how do I override the actual function to my own function without making a new class to hold QString?

Comment: If you created this in a subclass your implementation should overwrite the implementation of the super-class

Comment: I have just typed the code into my mainwindow.cpp 
its showing error: 
ambiguous overload for 'operator+'.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `QString operator+(QString a,QString b)`. The return type of the overloaded function is QString, not void. The compiler cannot differ between two overloads only differ by return type.

Comment: same error : 
ambiguous overload for'operator+' (operand types are QString and QString) ;